Database schemas export issue
We are currently using an Azure Marketplace image for our SAP HANA Express instance for development purposes. I need to migrate the database schemas from one Azure account to another, but I'm facing challenges because we do not have an SAP Customer Number, which prevents me from downloading the SAP HANA Studio software. I’ve also tried using command-line options, but they haven't worked. Any guidance or assistance on this matter would be highly appreciated.
Below command line option I have tried:
EXPORT "DD_USER" AS FILE = '/hana/backup/DD_USER_dump.zip' WITH REPLACE;


SAP HANA Studio is an Eclipse plug-in, which can be downloaded and used without SAP Customer Number. Instruction on how to configure the "SAP HANA Tools" plug-in in Eclipse can be found on the SAP Development Tools page.
